# Goldengate Microservices and Yum update

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I am in the process of using Ansible to run yum updates on my servers.  One I am in charge of has GG Microservices 19.1 installed on it.  Is it best practice to just shut down the Service Manager, therefore, stopping all replication and do the yum update, or do I need to stop each replication first then stop Service Manager before the yum update.  I am just trying to see what everyone else is doing.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yum is not supported with GoldenGate.  You have to use OPatch to patch GG Microservices.